# Stripe error : submitTokenToBackend error, unresolved identifier error

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am working on a stripe project on iOS. I followed the start guide on stripe website for a primary test.

For iOS app, their SDK had a built-in `addCardViewController`. So I just copy and paste the code to my `ViewController` file. However, now I am having an error which is, an unresolved identifier `submitToBackEnd`.

Can anyone tell me what the possible problem is?

Below I have added the code which I used:

```
 func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreateToken token: STPToken, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
    submitTokenToBackend(token, completion: { (error: Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            // Show error in add card view controller
            completion(error)
        }
        else {
            // Notify add card view controller that token creation was handled successfully
            completion(nil)

            // Dismiss add card view controller
            dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're missing the `submitTokenToBackend` function declaration. The Stripe documentation assumes you're writing it yourself. (it's mentioned here after the code block https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/custom#stpapiclient--stpcardparams)

The implementation varies greatly depending on what you use to send requests from your App to your backend. It's not exactly the same but you can look at this part of the Standard Example to see how it roughly works:

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/Example/Standard%20Integration%20(Swift)/MyAPIClient.swift#L25

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your respond. I am confused, it gives me so many source code to prepare the api to get the ephemeral key, such as ruby, go java and etc.  I check out their example, they use Heroku as backend. I am not currently using firebase, should i write the code on firebase to prepare for api?